How to upgrade Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 when do-release-upgrade blocks due to grub issue
I've got an 23.04 install that needs upgrading. I know 23.04 is past its support window.
Normally not much of an issue, but upgrading it to mantic runs in to some sort of a deadlock:
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Cannot upgrade this system

Due to a bug in grub, this system cannot be safely upgraded at this
time.

See https://launchpad.net/bugs/2039172.

Now, that bug has since been fixed, but never got ported back to 23.04 that I can make out. And every search I do on upgrading Grub only leads to posts about updating the bootloader, not Grub itself.
I also couldn't find a ppa or such for an upgraded grub. At this point, I am stuck. Is there a way to force this? Or another way to upgrade?

did you read the bug report?

Yes, as far as I understand, it got fixed, but still do-release-upgrade blocks.

Only solution was to replace the boot partition with an ext4 one.
